# Spyder debugger causes deep recursion

Tags: python-3.6, spyder, pdb

I am trying to debug a script using spyder debugger. When entering debugger mode, python return the following error :

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

My code does not use recursion. However, going up the traceback I see it is actually spyder's debugger `pdb` that triggers the recursion given that I see a bunch of the following repeated many times :

```
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\PythonEnvs\Python36Main\lib\site-packages\pdb.py", line 169, in __init__
    super(Pdb, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\PythonEnvs\Python36Main\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\debugger.py", line 232, in __init__
    OldPdb.__init__(self, completekey, stdin, stdout)
```

Any idea what is going on ? I tried on the machine of a colleague who is running 3.7 and he can debug without any issue.

EDIT : To the request, I tried a really simple script as shown herebelow :

```
def simpleFunction():
    print("this is a simple function")
```

Entering the debug on this simple script triggers the same issue. Note that before, I could run the debugger without problem. I do not know what has changed since then.

Comment: Please, add your code.

Comment: the code is quite extensive and is composed of multiple files. Since apparently this is not related to the code but rather to the Spyder debugger, I was assuming the script code is not necessary

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Without a simple and reproducible example, it's impossible for us to know what's going on, sorry.

Comment: It looks like an installation issue to me. Perhaps updating IPython with `conda update ipython` could fix it.